# Android app be blank without run it from debug in Lollipop 5.0

Tags: android, debugging, fragment, android-5.0-lollipop

i have a problem with developing Android app in Lollipop. I am using Nexus 7 (2012).

If my app was run from eclipse (run debug) then it work ok. But if i open it in app screen (on phone), it show blank screen (the actionbar and the drawer were still working) but the main content (i use fragments) was blank

[image]

Edited :

These are my code in MainActivity for loading fragment content :

```
mStacks = new HashMap<String, Stack<Fragment>>();
    mStacks.put(AppConstant.TEST_FRAGMENT, new Stack<Fragment>());

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    currentMenu = AppConstant.TEST_FRAGMENT;

    if (bundle != null) {
        currentMenu = bundle.getString(BaseAppConstant.INTENT_AL_SCREEEN_NAME_EXTRA);
    }

    if (currentMenu != null) {
        if (currentMenu.equals(AppConstant.TEST_FRAGMENT))
           pushFragments(new ListFragment(), false, true);
    }
```

Comment: there may be some issue which make fragment gone ..what are you using ..without code cannot guess naything

Comment: compare your code with the sample code/by_default of the drawer provided when u create your project hope u have something messd

Comment: thank you guys, i updated my codes, please take a look on that.